# PYTHON Return value on while

Tags: python, loops, return

Hi I have this code in python, I want the return and keep printing but it just return one time and print one time, Here's what i tried

```py
def car(distance,speed):
  while distance>0:
   distance=distance-20
   speed=speed-speed*0.05
   print('distance=',distance, 'speed is',speed)
   # Here's what i tried return but it just print one time
   return distance,speed

print(car(220,160))
```

Comment: Because ```return``` just stops your while loop, returns the value and never comes back to the loop. Maybe you want to assign distance and speed to some variable and make use of it?

Comment: instead of returning, add the datapoint to a list. return the list after your while loop finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return statement shifts the control back to calling function. Hence while is terminated. You can append the results and print after the end of while

```
def car(distance,speed):
  result = []
  while distance>0:
    distance=distance-20
    speed=speed-speed*0.05
    # Here's what i tried return but it just print one time
    result.append((distance,speed))

  for item in result:
      print('distance=',item[0],'speed is', item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is indented one level too many, therefore the loop terminates after one time. Make sure it is aligned to while.

Comment: That would only return last value of while loop and not every value

Answer (score 0):

A **return** statement is used to **end the execution of the function call and returns the result** (*value of the expression following the return keyword*) to the caller. The statements after the return statements (*in the function*) are not executed.

So in this case you're returning the first value and after that you're jumping out of the function.